# SelectedValue from another Combobox's source sub-property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Bit of a newbie question but I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

My structure is as follows

```
class Connection
{
   private static ObservableCollection<Connection> conlist = getConnections();
   private string _channel;
   //other fields 

   public string Channel
   {
      get
         { return this._channel; }
   }

   public static ObservableCollection<Connection> Ports
   {
      get
         { return conlist; }
   }

   private ObservableCollection<Connection> getConnections(string path)
   {
      //Gets list of connections from a file
   }
```

```
class Tab
{
   private Connection _channel;
   private string _title;

   public string Title
   {
      get
      { return this._title; }
   }

   public string Connection
   {
      get { return this._channel; }
   }
}
```

Now I want to have two comboboxes, one to select the Tab which will display the description and I want the other to display all the ports in Connection.Ports but have the selected value initially as the one in the Tab.Connection

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tab_combobox" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" DisplayMemberPath="Title" Tag="{Binding Channel}" SelectedIndex="0"/>


<ComboBox x:Name="tab_channel_combobox"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static model:Connection.Ports}}"
SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=tab_combobox}"
SelectedValuePath="Tag"
/>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you set `SelectedValuePath="Tag"` you must not use `Tag` in the property path of the SelectedValue Binding. Try `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=tab_combobox}"`

Comment: Fixed the question. My last response to you made it seem like I fixed the issue at stake

Comment: There is still `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ...}"`.